# type conversion in html to compare ngmodel

Tags: angular

I have this issue resolved in my .ts file, but I would like to solve in .html because I found it clearer.

```
    <mat-form-field class="form-view-mat-field"> 
      <mat-select [ngModel]="data?.number_to_string" name="name">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements;">
          <mat-option value={{element.id}}>{{element.name}}</mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

 const elements: Elements[] = [
  {id: "1", name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'}]
```

When data exists, it is:

```
data= {number_to_string: 2}
  or
data = {}
```

so, mat-select should be show "Helium" it doesn't because it's an int and needs a string.

I solve it in .ts with:

```
if(this.data){
      this.number_to_string = this.number_to_string ? this.data.number_to_string + "" : null;
 }
```

to avoid this conditions I would like to convert from int to string in html but I don't find how

Is it possible?